# How to make SVGs safe to use?

Tags: security, svg

I'm creating a custom set of icons for a design system. I would like to know whether there are security vulnerabilities by using:

1-Inline SVG

```html
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-search fa-w-16 form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="search" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
```

2-Calling the file hosted in the server

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="images/search.svg">
```

3-Not using them at all and create custom icon fonts instead. However, the maintenance is much higher for both designer and developer, not considering that in some situations they might not load properly.

Comment: What exactly are you worried about?

Comment: Inline SVG could potentially have some security/privacy issues if you are injecting third party SVGs into your page.  If they had script tags that could be a problem.  But if you are in control of the content, then there should be nothing to worry about.  As for `<img>` elements, there is nothing to worry about.  Browsers all have restrictions on what those SVGs can do. So they are safe also.

Comment: I agree with @PaulLeBeau that you shouldn't be worried about your own images and `<img>` element will not let anyone change your image. But it can be misleading if we are talking about third party files because there are other problems even using the `<img>` tag, where the user can be redirected to the image file itself instead of the page with the embedded image. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387722/is-there-any-way-to-make-user-uploaded-svg-images-safe-from-code-injection-etc) for more information about third party images.